# Need only product and category data in data migration

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

I am doing Magento data migration from 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.1. I need only and only product, category and attribute data. I am using new and different theme in 2.3.1, Ultimo.

I don't want any cutomer, sales etc., data.

Please assist with any changes required in config.xml or map.xml files. OR if you have any scripts, pls share with me.

Many thanks in advance.